Windows Instability Issues
I've been having this problem that the Windows works fine for 10 - 15 minutes, but it then freezes. What I mean by freeze is that if I have a browser window open, I open a new tab, it's either completely black or blank, or I can't type in the search bar for Microsoft Edge.
Task manager appears to be frozen as well. If I press Windows in the bottom left then the search bar will open, however upon trying to type in something:
a) There will be no text showing up in the search-bar area
b) The search window will be grey, similar to how it looks when its loading
The Windows key on my keyboard does not work, in essence the only thing responding is my mouse.
I've run chkdsk command on C: which is the SSD boot drive. It took approx. 90 minutes but  did not fix the problem.
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/mu2j1dt3hnt8hkc3gf1bw/System-Errors.evtx?rlkey=xxg4v5pnfusy4jo3vkv7gcs1w&st=w5jdsxo3&dl=0
I think it should also be noted that my Windows Event Viewer is not producing any specific error as from what I can see should be produced by such things, like freezes.
I would like to note that I tried resetting the system, I was out on my institution, I selected everything for the wipe to have it thoroughly reset, however it got stuck on the Windows logo and please wait, I force shut down the system and booted it up again, there was an error while resetting the system. All changes were undone
I started noticing these errors a day or two after installing Quick Heal Total Security, paid antivirus. However uninstalling and clean booting did not work.

Can you take a screenshot as this is happening and include that, particularly so we can see the black or grey boxes where you expect to be able to interact? When did this begin, and what was happening on your computer around that time? Have you completed any tests of the hardware, particularly the RAM (memory)? What are you system temps before this happens, and while it is happening? Have you checked for and installed the latest available drivers and firmware, and OS patches?

Also, dropbox or other file share links aren't very welcome here. If you have a screenshot, add that using the methods supported by this site (there's a button in the Editor for this). If you have something else, describe what you're trying to share. At the very least, you'll have to tell us what you are trying to share with us; there's no indicating what you're expecting us to find at that link or how it is relevant to your query.

Download the Windows 10 ISO from MS with media creation tool. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10 . Install it, either keeping files, or, if you've saved data elsewhere, completely wiping the disk and reinstalling, which will get rid of remnants of the "AV".

Sorry for the late replies, I will post screenshots in a bit.
The dropbox file is an .evtx file of my events.
I will not be able to provide screenshots as the events are really long.
I would like if I can fix this issue without reinstalling windows, however I am open to that as a last resort.
I will attach the evtx file just to be safe so you can parse it and view it.
System temps are normal, and while it's happening EVERY SINGLE process is frozen, nothing updates, file explorer is frozen as well, the processes are frozen, however I can still open windows, but they are blacked out.

There's not really a way for me to attach the EVTX file supported by the website, I have an XML form as well, however to my knowledge I cannot do it.
Also I cannot provide screenshots for the EVTX files as they are quite huge.
